# Control location of center of pie plot across multiple figures when setting labels of various lengths

Tags: matplotlib, pie-chart

I am generating one pie plot per figure and later saving that figure to disk (as PDF vector image). Some of these plots may have long labels, causing the pie center to shift over to the right.

I want to control the location of the center of the pie chart on each figure. In that way, when the figures are all placed vertically on a document (LaTeX in my case), the pie charts look aligned.

I have tried using plt.set_location() but this only seems to affect subplots when there is more than 1 plot.

A basic example of what I am doing is below. I want to be able to shift over the 2nd plot by enough padding. I can make a basic assumption about how long the longest label will be.

Any ideas?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.pie(fracs, labels=['Frogs', 'Hogs are really really cool mate', 'Dogs', 'Logs'])
```

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.pie(fracs, labels=['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.3, right=0.7)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html). Here `left` is the left side of the circle as measured as a fraction of the figure. `left=0` would mean the circle would touch the left side of the figure; `left=0.5` would have the left side in the center of the figure. Similar for `right=`.

Be careful not to set an option such as `tight_layout` ([`bbox_inches='tight`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html)) while saving, because that option intents to make these margins as small as possible.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to make the pie chart smaller. I want to keep the same radius size on this figure size. Also - I need to a way to always ensure the center of the circle is the same distance from the left side of the plot. Regardless of the length of the labels.

Comment: This solution is doing exactly what you asked for. You can adapt `left=` and `right=`to your situation. The size of the pie is exactly between left and right. You can also set your figsize wider. If you need more room at the left, it is normal the pie gets smaller. You could experiment with setting the fontsize smaller, and also by putting a `\n` in the names to get them printed on multiple lines.

Comment: Was this answer helpful?